# nicescroll on chrome - mouse wheel not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-chrome, nicescroll

I have this implementation for nicescroll :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   "use strict";

 $("html").niceScroll({cursorborder:"none" ,cursorcolor:"#393F48",cursorwidth :"12px",background:"#D5D5D5",autohidemode:"true"});  
}
```

The scrol is rendered ok but in Chrome (v37.0) the scroll wheel is not working. In firefox or opera everything works as expected. Also i have no js errors in console.

What is strange is that everything worked fine until 2 days ago. The code is in a wordpress theme and maybe the 4.0 update had something to do with it.

Any ideea?
Thanks